# C# Code Injection at runtime

Tags: c#, security, code-injection

I have interesting to try the security of my programs.

I have this simple fragment of code:

```
namespace WFACodeInjectionTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public int A = 0;
        public int B = 5;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( (A + B).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

At runtime it's possible in C# modify the value of variable A e B by another program ?

Comment: Please explain a bit more what do you mean and how you want to change them.

Comment: It's possible, but we need a little more information about the program you want to modify it from, because there's a lot of roads to follow such as `WriteProcessMemory`, `Reflection` etc.

Comment: @Bauss It's possible to have a simple example of code ?

Comment: How when I barely know what you exactly want to achieve nor any information about the other program.

Comment: @Bauss Another c# program...I want an example of another c# program for change the variable value when the program run...

Comment: Look the question linked to yours...